# reading nested lists from csv to pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trading a csv file row-wise:

```
for n in range(len(df_config)):
    init_list = df_config.at[n,'init_list'].split(",")
    init_list = list(map(float, init_list))
```

When I read a cell (init_list) from csv file it is read as follows:

```
'[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[.2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2],[.8, .7, .7, .7, .8, .8, .8, .8],[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]'
```

This is in string format.

I need to be able to read each individual list as per the index number. I am trying something like this:

```
    for idx,item in enumerate(init_list):
        df_templete[item] = init_list[idx]
```

I am looking to read the above list like:

```
idx = 0, then item = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
idx = 1, then item = [.2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2]
idx = 2, then item = [.8, .7, .7, .7, .8, .8, .8, .8]
idx = 3, then item = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Additional Information:

My input dataframe is as follows:

```
df_templete
Categories  AA  BB  CC  DD
Rock
Paper
Scissors
Lizard
Spock
```

I am looking to create the below dataframe:

```
Categories  AA  BB  CC  DD  Increse_AA  Increse_BB  Increse_CC  Increse_DD
Rock                            1           0.2       0.8          1
Paper                           1           0.2       0.8          1
Sissors                         1           0.2       0.7          1
Lizard                          1           0.2       0.7          1
Spock                           1           0.2       0.8          1
```

All these columns and rows come from same csv type file. with the above enumarate function, I was able to populate the values of increse columns incase they were same for all categories of one country but now since I have to pooulate individual values for category with respect to each column (`AA, BB, CC, DD`) I am trying to figure out a way to do this.

This is the first row of the csv file which i am using as an input to form the above dataframe:

```
Categories                  Country              init_list
Rock, Paper, Scissors,      AA, BB, CC, DD      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
Lizard, Spock                                   [.2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2],
                                                [.8, .7, .7, .7, .8, .8, .8, .8],
                                                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

which can be generated like so:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """\
Categories                  Country              init_list
Rock,Paper,Scissors,Lizard,Spock      AA,BB,CC,DD      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[.2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2, .2],[.8, .7, .7, .7, .8, .8, .8, .8],[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

Comment: Could you expand on your input some more please? What does the DataFrame look like? What do you want to the resulting DataFrame to look like?

Comment: Updated more details on the input and output.

Comment: It's still not clear where the `'[1, 1, ...][...]'` is coming from.

Comment: @Alex I think the first `[1, ..., 1]` is the `Increase_AA` column, the second `[.2, ..., .2]` is the `Increase_BB` column and so forth. What I think might be better when iterating through a Pandas DataFrame is `for index, row in dataframe.iterrows()`.

Comment: @TõnisPiip, that's labelled as the output they want to achieve. The code block above is labelled as input, and there are no lists/numbers in there.

Comment: You\re right, my bad. @RSM that can't be how the CSV file looks like, can it? What's the delimiter? Are the five categories the only five rows in the CSV? Usually CSVs are just rows of texts/numbers with a single type of delimiter (comma, semicolon or something else).

Comment: @TõnisPiip This is only one row separated by columns. Categories have all those 5 values in a single cell and to the right, there is the next cell with 4 country names.

Comment: @RSM, can you check the edit I have made creates the same dataframe?